# Classification when each level has probability assigned to it

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, beta-regression

The response variable in my dataset is a factor with six levels. For each observation, each level has been assigned a probability to be interpreted as the probability that the given observation is classified as that level. Here is a minimum working example with three predictors (X1, X2, X3) where the response factor has three levels (A, B, C).

```
set.seed(1)
X1 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 1)
X2 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 3, sd = 0.5)
X3 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 2)
prob_A <- runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 0.5)
prob_B <- runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 0.5)
prob_C <- 1 - prob_A - prob_B
dat <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3, prob_A, prob_B, prob_C)
head(round(dat, 3))

     X1    X2     X3 prob_A prob_B prob_C
1 4.374 3.567  8.228  0.385  0.349  0.266
2 5.184 3.556  6.155  0.345  0.227  0.427
3 4.164 2.565 13.239  0.325  0.324  0.351
4 6.595 3.105 11.039  0.037  0.307  0.656
5 5.330 3.035  9.888  0.451  0.133  0.415
6 4.180 2.169 11.393  0.066  0.464  0.470
```

So the probability that the first observation should be classified as level A is 0.385 and so forth. Note that the probabilities in each row add to 1.

I've read elsewhere that beta regression is useful in cases where the response is a probability, but I don't know how to apply it when the response is a vector of probabilities. I've tried running a separate beta regression for each level with unimpressive results. Is there a classification method available that uses all of the probabilities in a single model?

Comment: Without dealing with your last paragraph, I think the language you used makes it unclear.  There is a difference between "can be classified as" and "is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dirichlet regression is the extension of beta regression for compositional data (i.e., proportions for several levels that sum to 1). Dirichlet::Beta regression is like Multinomial::Binomial. Thus, the Dirichlet distribution is a family for multivariate continuous observations that sum to 1. The common parameterization of the corresponding regression model links the shape parameters of the distribution to linear predictors. An alternative parameterization links expectations and a precision parameter to linear predictors. Both are available in the R package `DirichletReg` at https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=DirichletReg. It also comes with a working paper (http://epub.wu.ac.at/4077/) that explains the model and accompanying software implementation.

For your simulated data you can first set up the response in the package's data structure

```
library("DirichletReg")
dat$prob <- DR_data(dat[, 4:6])
plot(dat$prob)
```

[image: ternary plot]

And then the common model yields:

```
m1 <- DirichReg(prob ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = dat)
summary(m1)
## Call:
## DirichReg(formula = prob ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = dat)
## 
## Standardized Residuals:
##             Min       1Q   Median      3Q     Max
## prob_A  -1.5162  -0.7482   0.0073  0.7027  1.5018
## prob_B  -1.5230  -0.7092  -0.0718  0.7132  1.5352
## prob_C  -2.4742  -0.6599   0.0198  0.7237  2.4825
## 
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 1: prob_A
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)  0.149975   0.290485   0.516    0.606
## X1           0.041932   0.032236   1.301    0.193
## X2          -0.014891   0.060937  -0.244    0.807
## X3           0.002259   0.015774   0.143    0.886
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 2: prob_B
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept) -0.21412    0.29939  -0.715    0.474
## X1           0.04501    0.02928   1.538    0.124
## X2           0.05603    0.06143   0.912    0.362
## X3           0.01039    0.01596   0.651    0.515
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Beta-Coefficients for variable no. 3: prob_C
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)  0.959877   0.290775   3.301 0.000963 ***
## X1          -0.014603   0.032007  -0.456 0.648229    
## X2          -0.004648   0.063289  -0.073 0.941459    
## X3           0.009748   0.017118   0.569 0.569035    
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Significance codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Log-likelihood: 1035 on 12 df (91 BFGS + 1 NR Iterations)
## AIC: -2045, BIC: -1986
## Number of Observations: 1000
## Link: Log
## Parametrization: common
```

Similarly for the alternative parametrization:

```
m2 <- DirichReg(prob ~ X1 + X2 + X3 | X1 + X2 + X3, data = dat, model = "alternative")
summary(m2)
## Call:
## DirichReg(formula = prob ~ X1 + X2 + X3 | X1 + X2 + X3, data = dat, model =
## "alternative")
## 
## Standardized Residuals:
##             Min       1Q   Median      3Q     Max
## prob_A  -1.5171  -0.7489   0.0069  0.7019  1.5066
## prob_B  -1.5229  -0.7090  -0.0722  0.7113  1.5360
## prob_C  -2.4771  -0.6590   0.0191  0.7222  2.4842
## 
## MEAN MODELS:
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Coefficients for variable no. 1: prob_A
## - variable omitted (reference category) -
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Coefficients for variable no. 2: prob_B
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept) -0.364618   0.284715  -1.281    0.200
## X1           0.002721   0.030753   0.088    0.929
## X2           0.071877   0.061001   1.178    0.239
## X3           0.008084   0.015302   0.528    0.597
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Coefficients for variable no. 3: prob_C
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
## (Intercept)  0.809268   0.251950   3.212  0.00132 **
## X1          -0.057788   0.028343  -2.039  0.04146 * 
## X2           0.011392   0.055545   0.205  0.83750   
## X3           0.007835   0.014150   0.554  0.57976   
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## 
## PRECISION MODEL:
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept) 1.503549   0.253671   5.927 3.08e-09 ***
## X1          0.014554   0.027081   0.537    0.591    
## X2          0.007847   0.053569   0.146    0.884    
## X3          0.008116   0.014361   0.565    0.572    
## ------------------------------------------------------------------
## Significance codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Log-likelihood: 1035 on 12 df (85 BFGS + 1 NR Iterations)
## AIC: -2045, BIC: -1986
## Number of Observations: 1000
## Links: Logit (Means) and Log (Precision)
## Parametrization: alternative
```

Comment: I'd like to learn more about Dirichlet regression.  Can you give us a few sentences that motivates its use?

Comment: @FrankHarrell, thanks, I've edited my post and added a few sentences at the beginning along with a link to Marco Meier's working paper on the DirichletReg package. The main idea is that multinomial is to binomial like Dirichlet to beta regression.

Comment: Thanks, this like exactly what I need. I've run a model but I'm getting an odd error when trying to make predictions with a test set. I've posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626861/error-when-predicting-with-dirichletreg-package-in-r